# calling async_read again is throwing exception

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

I have the following code:

```
 void GnutellaApp::HandleRead (boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket)
{
     char buf[128];
     try {
     boost::asio::async_read(   socket,
                                boost::asio::buffer(buf),
                                boost::asio::transfer_all(),
                                boost::bind(&GnutellaApp::HandleRead,
                                            this,
                                            boost::ref(socket)
                                            )
                            );
     }
        catch (boost::system::system_error const& e)
        {
            std::cout << "Warning:  " << e.what() << std::endl;
        }
}
```

When `HandleRead` is called and `async_read` is executed, its throwing an exception. In order to asynchronously wait for next request we need to call `async_read` again, right?
First call to `async_read` succeeds.

i am getting following exception

I am getting following exception

```
Gnutella.exe!std::_Ref_count_base::_Incwref() Line 113  C++
    Gnutella.exe!std::_Ptr_base<void>::_Resetw<void>(void * _Other_ptr, std::_Ref_count_base * _Other_rep) Line 458 C++
    Gnutella.exe!std::_Ptr_base<void>::_Resetw<void>(const std::_Ptr_base<void> & _Other) Line 445  C++
    Gnutella.exe!std::weak_ptr<void>::weak_ptr<void><void>(const std::shared_ptr<void> & _Other, void * * __formal) Line 994    C++
    Gnutella.exe!boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::async_receive<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,GnutellaApp,boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<GnutellaApp *>,boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > > >(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service_base::base_implementation_type & impl, const boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 & buffers, int flags, boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,GnutellaApp,boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<GnutellaApp *>,boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > > & handler) Line 292   C++
    Gnutella.exe!boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::async_receive<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,GnutellaApp,boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<GnutellaApp *>,boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > > >(boost::asio::detail::win_iocp_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::implementation_type & impl, const boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 & buffers, int flags, boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,GnutellaApp,boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<GnutellaApp *>,boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > > && handler) Line 359   C++
    Gnutella.exe!boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >::async_read_some<boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,GnutellaApp,boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<GnutellaApp *>,boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > > >(const boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 & buffers, boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,GnutellaApp,boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<GnutellaApp *>,boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > > && handler) Line 846    C++
    Gnutella.exe!boost::asio::detail::read_op<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,GnutellaApp,boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<GnutellaApp *>,boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > >::operator()(const boost::system::error_code & ec, unsigned int bytes_transferred, int start) Line 273  C++
    Gnutella.exe!boost::asio::async_read<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> >,boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1,boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t,boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,GnutellaApp,boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<GnutellaApp *>,boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > >(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > & s, const boost::asio::mutable_buffers_1 & buffers, boost::asio::detail::transfer_all_t completion_condition, boost::_bi::bind_t<void,boost::_mfi::mf1<void,GnutellaApp,boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &>,boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value<GnutellaApp *>,boost::reference_wrapper<boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > > > > && handler) Line 535   C++
    Gnutella.exe!GnutellaApp::HandleRead(boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > & socket) Line 232    C++
>   Gnutella.exe!boost::_mfi::mf1<void,GnutellaApp,boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > &>::operator()(GnutellaApp * p, boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp,boost::asio::stream_socket_service<boost::asio::ip::tcp> > & a1) Line 165 C++
    Gnutella.exe!boost::_bi::list2<boost::_bi::value
```

Comment: i am getting follwing exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear as if you are holding a stale reference.

Besides,     `boost::asio::buffer(buf)` is a glaring offense, since `buf` is a stack-local, but `async_read` is... well ***async***.

The common patterns are

- make `buf` and `socket` class members (so that they are sure to outlive the async requests)
- make `buf` and `socket` shared (`boost::shared_ptr<boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket>`) which you can just pass/bind by value:

  ```
     boost::bind(&GnutellaApp::HandleRead,
                  this,
                  socket
               )
  ```

  would just keep the socket alive as long as the bound function call is kept alive in the io service, by virtue of the `shared_ptr`

Comment: I concur with this assessment.  The asynchronous operations are designed to not throw exceptions and instead pass errors to the completion handlers as their first parameter.  The exception being thrown strongly suggest that the socket's lifetime has ended prior to the second call to `async_read()`.